# Block root access remotely like ssh and putty

Tags: 18.04, ssh, security

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu and I have a Ubuntu instance in GCP and want to restrict the root access from the outside like ssh and putty, but however I want to access root by using the command `su root` . Is there any way to achieve that it will good for security.

I tried `PermitRootLogin no` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` but it didn't work. I can still access root using putty.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Did you restart the ssh service after the configuration change - `sudo systemctl restart sshd`? Which version is your Ubuntu?

Comment: yes i did, version Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. command i used was `service ssh restart`

Comment: Ah, you need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (`sshD`) instead of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: fyi:  ssh_config is the client config (ie. going from the box), where as sshd_config is the server config (ie. going into the box; d=daemon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the `openssh-sever` configuration you need to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`  file, where *d* stands for *daemon*. The configuration file mentioned in the question - `ssh_config`  - is dedicated to the `openssh-client`. Otherwise the directive you are using - `PermitRootLogin no` - is correct.

Comment: I just checked "sshd_config" in one of my server, and right now it's "#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password" (commented out). Do I need to uncomment and edit it to: "PermitRootLogin no" ? Thanks.

Comment: Password authentication is set to no already: "PasswordAuthentication no"

Comment: Hi, @Jags. Usually, within the default configuration files, the comment out lines show the default settings. I've read the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sshd_config.5.html), and I think with `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` you should be able to login as root via ssh by key based authentication - for this purpose into the file `/root/.ssh/authorized_key` must be added any relevant public key (I will check this in practice tomorrow). On other hand `PermitRootLogin no` should deny any kind of login as root via ssh.

Comment: At all while the file `/root/.ssh/authorized_key` doesn't exist the two options must be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to be extra clear, I've enabled SSH key based login from my desktop PC, and have disabled password based logins. Now I'd like to block "root logins". Though once I login (key based login) as a non-root user, I can still become root by "sudo" or sudo su", is that correct?

Comment: @Jags, yes, correct, also `sudo -i` is applicable :)

Comment: I just tested on one fresh Ubuntu 18.04: With the default directive `(#)PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` if there is added a pub key into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` I'm able to login as root via ssh and key based authentication. Once the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is deleted the root login is not possible.

Comment: Thank you so much.